# React Web Broken on Apple M1

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I've recently updated from Intel to M1 Max and all my react web project sadly broke with the same error:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/giulioserra/Documents/Siti Web/CTS/ctsapp/node_modules/react-native-image-placeholder-cache/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (8:9):

   6 | 
   7 | 
>  8 |   state = {
     |         ^
   9 |     isLoaded:false,
  10 |     path:''
  11 |   }

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

I have no babel config file and event installing the package seems to do nothing, here are my specs:

Mac Monterey M1 Max,
Node: v15.14.0

here is my package.info file:

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.30",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.14.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.4.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "firebase": "^7.17.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "query-string": "^6.13.5",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-geocode": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-image-placeholder-cache": "^1.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "redirect": "^0.2.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "uuid": "^8.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any hints?
Thanks

Comment: Try updating node to 16

Comment: @JBallin upgraded to v16.16.0 still having the same error.

Comment: Resolved downgrading to node 14.14, thanks